# ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into, when mapped with @onetomany and having composite primary key on child side

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one, composite-primary-key, hibernate-onetomany

```
            1. @OneToMany (Uni Direction):

            Parent:

            @Entity
            @Table(name = "POLICY")
            @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_POLICY", sequenceName = "SEQ_POLICY", allocationSize = 1)
            public class Policy implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_POLICY")
            @Column(name = "POLICY_ID")
            private BigDecimal policyID;

            @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "POLICY_ID")
            private List<Carrier> carriers = new ArrayList<>();

            ...
            }

            Child: (Having composite Primary key)

            @Entity
            @Table(name = "CARRIER")
            public class Carrier implements Serializable{

            @EmbeddedId
            private CarrierPK carrierPK;



               ...getters and setters

                }

                Child Primary key:

                @Embeddable
                public class CarrierPK implements Serializable{

                    @Column(name="POLICY_ID")
                    private BigDecimal policyId;

                    @Column(name="TYPE_ID") 
                    private BigDecimal typeId; 

                    @Column(name="S_NUMBER")
                    private BigDecimal sNumber;

                 // getters and setter
                // hashcode and equals


                }
```

Dao code: part of the save method

```
 public class Bo{
    public void savePolicy(){        
                List<Carrier> carriers = new ArrayList<>();
                for(CarrierVo c:carriersList)     //CarrierVo  pojo from ui
                {
                 // to copy properties form pojo to entity 
                 Carrier cEntity =  somecalss.method(c)
                   CarrierPK cPK = new CarrierPK();
                    cPK.setSNumber(c.getSNumber()); 
                    cPK.setTypeId(c.getTypeId()); 
                    cEntity.setCarriersPK(cPK);
                    carriers .add(cEntity);
                }
                policyEntity.setCarriers(carriers );
                em.persist(policyEntity);
        }    
}
```

When I am persisting , I am getting the following error:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PROJECT"."CARRIER"."POLICY_ID")

I tried with @OneToMany bidirectional mapping also got the same error.

Comment: Share your insertion code.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I have added the persistence logic just now, please check once.

Answer (score 0):

It has the same name POLICY_ID for fields policyID and carriers. I think it is not correct to map list of carriers as "POLICY_ID" inPolicy entity in JoinColumn annotation. Maybe there must be something like "CARRIER_ID" or check table description what the column should be. Try to fix it. And, if it is possible that carriers can be nullable or empty, you can add `nullable=true` for `List<Carrier> carriers` mapping.

Comment: hi, I have re verified both policy and carrier table and both have same column name policy_id, policy_id in carrier table is foreign key.  yes carriers can be nullable, If I want to have this option then I need to go for OneTomany bidirectional, If I am not wrong.

Comment: You have 2 POLICY_ID columns in Policy table, I thought, the problem was here. For me it is a strange design, so. Can you add mapping in CarrierPK  for policyId if it was not a BigDecimal but Policy entity with ManyToOne relationship?
If no, you can make carriers nullable and persist policy firstly and after that - carriers list.
Also, you can look for jpa MapsId annotation for POLICY_ID: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147161/ora-01400-cannot-insert-null-into-when-mapped-with-onetomany-and-having-compo/58149538?noredirect=1#comment102687583_58149538